# Stop a jQuery each() loop

Tags: jquery, each

so I have  multiple instances of a .item class but are broken up into difference sections (its a per-determined class and cant change)... now the issue is that I have the code using :odd to change the background of the items, but when the the next section starts it goes off of the last one. so:

if Instance One has 3 items, then item 2 will be highlighted.
then Instance Two will have the first item highlited. it doesnt "start" the loop again.  Hope that makes sense.

this is the code I have so far:

```
$('.item').each(function(){
    $('.item:odd').css('background','#FFF4F9');
});
```

so Instance 1:

```
<div class="item" id="linkitem"><div class="link-item"><a title="" target="_blank" href="#">LINK</a></div></div>
<div class="item" id="linkitem"><div class="link-item"><a title="" target="_blank" href="#">LINK</a></div></div>
<div class="item" id="linkitem"><div class="link-item"><a title="" target="_blank" href="#">LINK</a></div></div>
```

Instance 2:

```
<div class="item" id="linkitem"><div class="link-item"><a title="" target="_blank" href="#">LINK</a></div></div>
<div class="item" id="linkitem"><div class="link-item"><a title="" target="_blank" href="#">LINK</a></div></div>
<div class="item" id="linkitem"><div class="link-item"><a title="" target="_blank" href="#">LINK</a></div></div>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: There is the `:nth-child(odd)` CSS pseudo class which pretty much does exactly what you want, without the need for any JavaScript at all. Also, you cannot have multiple items that have the same ID.

Comment: $('.item').each(function(index,value){ use the index to declare a return false if(index == something){ return false}. that will stop the loop.

Comment: You have six elements with the same `id`. Therefore you have invalid html, so don't be surprised if things break (admittedly this problem isn't affected by the duplicates, but other issues may arise).

Answer (score 3):

The selector used `$('.item:odd')`regrdless of in a loop or not will index all the class=item on page

To isolate `odd` within a container:

```
 $('.container').each(function(){
     $(this).find('.item:odd').css('background','#FFF4F9');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid having to break out of the loop, or test where the element falls, why not simply use the following:

```
$('.listitem').parent().find('.listitem:odd').css('background','#F00');
```

This takes the `.listitem` selector, looks to the parent and then finds the `:odd` children of that parent, so in each parent element, whatever that might be, the 'numbering' is re-started.

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/47Jbm/).

Answer (score 1):

Just return false in your each handler function

Answer (score 1):

Using `return false` inside the `each` loop will break out the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to constrain your loop to a container of some sort. Right now it looks like you are making every other .item in the whole document a different color. If you want only every other row in the container that you want. So if you had:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item></div>
  <div class="item></div>
  <div class="item></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item></div>
  <div class="item></div>
  <div class="item></div>
</div>
```

You could use the following code:

```
$('.container').each(function(){
    $('.item:odd').css('background','#FFF4F9');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

at your code example there is no reason at all using .each you are just running the same lookup 3 times.